# Как поместить message.text в caption для фото в aiogram API python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как поместить message.text в caption для фото в aiogram API python? Делаю тг бота для своих нужд, хочу чтобы при рассылке я могу просто отправить фото с текстом как в обычном лс чате и ровно так же отправилось всем пользователям. Но вот незадача aiogram обрабатывает только по одному типу сообщений и я не знаю как message.text впихнуть в caption для send_photo. Помогите люди добрые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def handle_docs_photo(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=message.photo[0].file_id, caption=message.caption)
```

Так же на сколько я вас понял вы бы хотели отправить это **всем пользователям**, что означает что у вас есть какой то список всех **телеграм id** пройдясь по которому вы можете отправить **"всем"** фото с нужным для вас описанием. Это можно сделать примерно так:

```
idList = []  # массив с telegram id юзеров
for ID in idList:
    await bot.send_photo(ID, photo=message.photo[0].file_id, caption=message.caption)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этих нужд удобнее использовать [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/)

Например:

```
async def normal_handler(event):
    text2 = "тут текст который вам нужен"
    await client.send_file(chanel_id, event.media, caption=text2)
```

Comment: Считаю ваш ответ не верным. Человек чётко указал что он хочет получить ответ для aiogram, что подразумевает что вы должны дать либо общий пример(или псевдокод) либо код работающий на aiogram. Так же не вижу никакой обьективной причины почему в данном случае "Telethon" будет удобнее кроме лично ваших предпочтений.